# Testing differences between two patterns of values

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

In a perceptual experiment participants were asked to modify three parameters of a sound synthesis model in order to match a particular sound they had in mind. The starting point for each provided sound was a preset of the three parameters.

I ask which is the correct statistical analysis that can be perform to assess whether the results of the three parameters taken together are actually different from those of the initial combination of values of the presets.

I provide more details:
19 participants were provided with 12 sounds, repeated twice in a randomized order for a total of 24 trials. Each sound was synthesized by considering a value for each of three parameters (let's call them, parameterA_initial, parameterB_initial, parameterC_initial). After the adjustment experiment, the values of parameterA_initial, parameterB_initial, parameterC_initial are changed for each sound and for each participant (let's call them parameterA_modified, parameterB_modified, parameterC_modified).

How can it be assessed that the pattern (parameterA_modified, parameterB_modified, parameterC_modified) is significantly different from the pattern (parameterA_initial, parameterB_initial, parameterC_initial) considering all participants and all sounds?

Can anyone suggest a function to be used in the R program for the analysis?